# Setting Object to Chrome Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to save an object via the chrome.storage API. The relevant code is:

```
 var images = null;     
 var storage = chrome.storage.sync;
 var key = "key";

 images = getImages(source);
 alert(images.length); // returns 4

 storage.set({key: images});

 storage.get("key", function(result) {
    alert(result.length); // returns undefined
 });
```

I'm tested that immediately after the `getImages()` function, images is a wrapped set JQuery object with a length of 4. However, when I try to access `images.length` via the `storage.get` callback, the result is undefined.

Could someone help identify the error in how I am storing and/or retrieving this JQuery object?

### Update 1:

Thank you all for your help. As clarification for the use case, I am using `chrome.storage` instead of `localStorage`  because I plan to pass extension info to another script.

Fortunately, TranQ/Xan's solution has enabled me to access the array via the `storage.get` call.

I'm still experiencing issues working with the wrapped set JQuery object stored in the array but I'll post a separate question since the current solution encapsulates broader use cases.

Comment: Why not to go for `localStorage` ? Using `chrome.storage` returns undefined at first place..

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar: Web storage and chrome storage for extensions serve different use cases, you can't just swap one for the other.

Comment: Try `console.log(result)`. To retrieve the object you stored in there, you might have to use `result['key']`

Comment: Two things to keep in mind. chrome.storage mostly only supports primitive types, depending on what kind of jQuery objects you have `set` might be failing. The other thing is `set` is async so `get` might run and return undefined before `set` has committed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the question doesn't specify the use case it's premature to rule out localStorage as a valid solution. Given the sample code, localStorage could easily be used instead.

Comment: @abraham: If the OP's using Chrome storage, presumably they're doing that *on purpose* because they're storing extension info, not info related to the displayed page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder or maybe they read a blog post about making Chrome extensions and don't realize there are alternatives. It's always dangerous to jump  to conclusions in programing.

Comment: @abraham: I don't think I'm the one jumping or, as Occam put it, "multiplying entities," but whatever. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TranQ's comment is on point.

Presumably, `images` is an array. You store that array under the `"key"` key.

When you execute the `get()` function, it [returns an *object*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-get) populated with all key-value pairs you asked, even if you only ask for one key.

So, `result` is an object `{key : [/* something */]}`. Objects do not have a `length` property, and you get `undefined`

You need to use `result.key` (or `result["key"]`) to access your array.

Comment: E.g., `result.key.length` should be 4. Nice one.